# Код который на 100% приводит к deadlock

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне нужно написать максимально простой код который в 100% случаев запуска будет приводить к взаимной блокировке, но все примеры которые я рассматриваю дают только некоторую вероятность. Возможно ли такое написать, если да, то как бы это могло выглядеть в самом простом варианте?

Comment: два клиента (потока), два ресурса. Первый клиент захватывает первый ресурс, второй клиент - второй ресурс. После этого первый клиент пытается захватить второй ресурс и попадает в состояние ожидания. Зеркально - второй клиент и первый ресурс. Оба ждут: дедлок.

Comment: @Igor, а как обеспечить 100% гарантию, что они успеют захватить по одному ресурсу, а не один из потоков успеет захватить оба? Это один из вероятностных методов даже если его обложить sleep'ами. Тут только пачка других блокировок помогает.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");

            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");

            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");

            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");

            synchronized (Lock1) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

[Источник](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_deadlock.htm)

Comment: Не вижу,что именно обеспечивает полную гарантию, что один из потоков не успеет захватить обе блокировки. Хотя в целом для реального использования должно подойти.

Answer (score 11):

Проще всего, наверное, запустить в одном synchronized-методе ожидание самого себя в другом потоке.

```
public synchronized static void deadlock() {
    try {
        Thread t = new Thread(Test::deadlock);
        t.start();
        t.join();
    } catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/yTbiKY

---

Ещё более короткий блокирующийся код:

```
new Semaphore(0).acquire();
```

но в нём нет многопоточности, так что это в зависимости от вашего представления может или может не быть deadlock'ом.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/k1izqy

Comment: Это, кстати, выглядит куда надёжнее ожидания фиксированного времени.

Comment: Классный трюк!!!

Comment: @Qwertiy: Спасибо :)